# Create multiple lists from pandas df with conditional logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops

I have a df that looks like this:

```
var1 var2 var3
0    a    1
0    b    7
0    c    5
0    d    4
0    z    8
1    t    9
1    a    2
2    p    3
..   ..   ..
60   c    3
```

I'm attempting to create lists of each set of values from `var2` that correspond to a given value from `var1`. So, my output would look something like this:

```
list_0: a, b, c, d, z
list_1: t, a
list_2: p
list_60: c
```

Currently I'm trying to work out a loop to do this, something like:

```
for i in range(df.var2.max()):
    var2_i = (x for x in df.var1.to_list())
```

Though the lists don't seem to be iteratively created here. Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `join` aggregation and [`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) to rename index:

```
df.groupby('var1')['var2'].agg(', '.join).add_prefix('list_')
```

[out]

```
var1
list_0     a, b, c, d, z
list_1              t, a
list_2                 p
list_60                c
Name: var2, dtype: object
```

---

or for python lists use `list` aggregation:

```
df.groupby('var1')['var2'].agg(list).add_prefix('list_')
```

[out]

```
var1
list_0     [a, b, c, d, z]
list_1              [t, a]
list_2                 [p]
list_60                [c]
Name: var2, dtype: object
```

---

#### Update

I think I see what you're trying to achieve, my *strong* advice would be to use a python `dict` instead of "independent lits" - with the keys being `list_0`, `list_1`, etc...

**Example**

```
d = df.groupby('var1')['var2'].agg(list).add_prefix('list_').to_dict()

print(d['list_0'])
```

[out]

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z']
```

If you absolutely insist on independent lists, then use the `globals()` object, and update with a `for` loop *(for the avoidance of doubt, I do not recommend this method - check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) for more info)*:

```
s = df.groupby('var1')['var2'].agg(list).add_prefix('list_')

for var, lst in s.iteritems():
    globals()[var] = lst
```

You should now have independent lists with associated variable names.

Comment: So, df.groupby returns a groupby object, not independent lists.

Comment: @LMGagne see last part of the update - using `globals()` object

Comment: thanks for updating your answer, it's much more clear now and I appreciate the link to the other post that outlines why the thing I actually want might screw me over in the end.